# How to pass KeyVault secrets to a template or a script file in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-keyvault

I have this YAML file:

```
  steps:
      - task: AzureKeyVault@2
        displayName: Get secret from AzureVault
        inputs:
            azureSubscription: 'subName'
            KeyVaultName: 'vaultName'
            SecretsFilter: 'mySecret'
            RunAsPreJob: true

      - template: \pipelines\templates\vm_setup.yml
        parameters:
            os_pass: $(mySecret)
```

How do I use mySecret inside myScript.ps1 or inside myTemplate.yml?
I tried to pass it as an argument, or map it to an env variable then pass that env variable as an argument but neither worked!

My myTemplate.yml looks like this:

```
parameters:
    - name: os_pass
      type: string

steps:

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Trial
  inputs:
      targetType: 'filepath'
      filePath: '${{ parameters.workingDirectory }}\myScript.ps1'
      arguments: >-
          - OS_Pass ${{ parameters.os_pass }}
```

And this is myScript.ps1

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$OS_Pass
)

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $OS_Pass -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList 'admin', $password

Write-Host '---------'
Write-Host $OS_Pass
```

Doing so the secret is now a string! How do I pass it without changing its type?

Comment: When you say "neither worked", please explain *how* it didn't work. What behavior did you see? Can you provide the YAML for the approaches that didn't work?

Comment: @jsnoobie Your edit does not help things. You write, "How do I pass it without changing its type?" But KeyVault secrets are just strings. This is according to Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/about-secrets. "From a developer's perspective, Key Vault APIs accept and return secret values as strings."

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at the official documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-secret-variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbash.

There are a few different ways to accomplish what you want to do. Without knowing exactly what you want to do, it is hard to recommend a specific method to use. Take a look above and let us know if that resolves your issue.

Comment: None of this address the question. The link uses the secret in "inline" PowerShell. I want to use it in a file or a template.

Comment: @jsnoobie It absolutely answers your question. Whether it's an inline script or not is irrelevant: You pass the secret in as an environment variable via the an `env:` block, then reference it as an environment variable.

Comment: @DanielMann I add more snippets from my code up there where I am unable to pass my Key Vault secrets as secrets. I can only pass them as strings.

Comment: KeyVault secrets are strings. What type are you expecting them to be?

Comment: @ddastrodd doesn't that expose them?

Comment: Key Vault is focused on safely storing data that you don’t want floating around your application in config files and the like. The secrets themselves are securely stored but once accessed its up to you to handle them correctly.